# How to get push notification to do a quick display before just going to notification bar

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm not sure what it's called where the notification does a "quick display" on your device before just going to the notification bar. An example of what I'm talking about can be found [here](https://xmonkeys360.com/2019/12/09/fcm-configuration-in-xamarin-forms-part-ii/) (the gif under Android Output). You can see when he pushes the button to get the notification it displays the notification for 2-3 seconds before it goes away and just the notification tray icon is left.

How can I get this to happen for my notifications? Right now when I test out a notification send from Postman it just goes to my device and goes straight to having an icon display on my notification bar without the quick display.

Here is my **SendLocalNotification** method in my **FirebaseService** class (I'm assuming that it's a setting here where I'm building out the notification but I could be wrong):

```
void SendLocalNotification(string body)
    {
        //Unique request code to avoid PendingIntent collision.
        var requestCode = new Random().Next();

        // accept intent
        var acceptIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        acceptIntent.SetAction("ACCEPT_ACTION");
        var pendingIntentAccept = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, requestCode, acceptIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        // decline intent
        var declineIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        declineIntent.SetAction("DECLINE_ACTION");
        var pendingIntentDecline = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, requestCode, declineIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .AddAction(0, "Accept", pendingIntentAccept)
            .AddAction(0, "Decline", pendingIntentDecline)

            .SetContentTitle("Content Title")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.laundry_basket_icon_15875)
            .SetContentText("content text")
            .SetContentInfo("content info")
            .SetSubText("sub text")                
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetShowWhen(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntentAccept)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntentDecline);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            notificationBuilder.SetChannelId(AppConstants.NotificationChannelName);
        }

        var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
    }
```

Please let me know if code is needed from other classes.

Comment: Do you want to get content from the firebase notification before the notification is pushed? If so , you can get the content from `public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)` in `FirebaseMessagingService`, you can get the content by `var body = message.GetNotification().Body;`

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I really just want that 2-3 second quick display thing (sorry...not sure what it's called) at the top of the screen when the notification first comes in.

Comment: You can use `Messagingcenter` to send a message to PCL in `OnMessageReceived` method, then pop up a aler tDialog, after that, you can execute `SendLocalNotification()` to push a notification.

Comment: Thanks Leon Lu. I could do that. I was really just hoping that there would be something natively built into push notifications to give me that little "quick display" thing at the top of the screen once one came in.

Comment: You can try to run your code in the physical device, this performance will much better than emulator.